# How to update an array with his index number in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

my User Model has an cart with items (Array). I want to check if there is enough stock for each item in his cart and if not, to update the quantity of the item in his cart to the available stock (productId is populated).

```
   }                   
})
```

Well 'cart.items[i].quantity' would be too easy, it's not working :D

User:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Product:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: How does the document look like? Can post some sample documents.

Comment: Added screenshots (yeah i know productId is not the same, it's an example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the code you provided.

```
user.cart.items.forEach((item, i) => {
   if (item.quantity > item.productId.stock) {
      User.findByIdAndUpdate(user._id, {'cart.items[i].quantity': item.productId.stock})
   }                   
})
```

From the above code i can see that we have the `productId` of the item to be updated. So why use index when we have `productId` ? Anyways i have created a sample document based on your screenshots and created a query which updates the `quantity` based on `productId`. You can go to the mongo playground link and run the query and do tweaks as per your needs.

Try this query-

```js
db.collection.update({
  _id: 1
},
{
  "$set": {
    "cart.items.$[element].quantity": 2   /**where 2=item.productId.stock*/
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "element.productId": 100
    }
  ]
})
```

Here is [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FE65cz4P5eQ)

**Edit :**

If you still want to do it with index.

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: 1
},
{
  "$set": {
    "cart.items.1.quantity": 2/**where 1 is index and 2=item.productId.stock*/
    
  }
})
```

Here is [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/N68PVPWl10q)

Comment: Thanks for upvote. I have updated the answer for index query as well.